# Form value handling

Tags: php, forms, input

Is there a better/lazier/faster/more efficient way to assign the $_POST values to class' properties when submitting a form? What counts as best practice? What would be the best way to handle this in a real world situation?

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->field1 = $_POST['field1'];
  $this->field2 = $_POST['field2'];
  $this->field3 = $_POST['field3'];
  $this->field4 = $_POST['field4'];
  $this->field5 = $_POST['field5'];
  $this->field6 = $_POST['field6'];
  $this->field7 = $_POST['field7'];
  $this->field8 = $_POST['field8'];
  $this->field9 = $_POST['field9'];
  $this->field10 = $_POST['field10'];
}
```

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. Look up what *SOLID principles* are.

Comment: if you `json_encode` and then `json_decode` the `$_POST` variable (well, any associative array) you'll end up with a very similar structure... or loop via `foreach`.  But what you are really missing is validating/sanitizing/escaping the data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
<?php

$_POST['bar'] = 'Soap';

class DirtyFoo
{
    public $bar;
    public $baz;
}

$foo = new DirtyFoo;
foreach($foo as $p => $v)
    $foo->$p = $_POST[$p] ?? '';

var_dump($foo);
```

Output:

```
object(DirtyFoo)#1 (2) {
["bar"]=>
string(4) "Soap"
["baz"]=>
string(0) ""
}
```